# relation between support vectors and accuracy in case of RBF kernel

Tags: matlab, kernel, svm, training-data

I am using RBF kernel matlab function.
On couple of dataset as I go on increasing sigma value the number of support vectors increase and accuracy increases.
While in case of one data set, as I increase the sigma value, the support vectors decrease and accuracy increases.
I am not able to analyze the relation between support vectors and accuracy in case of RBF kernel.

Comment: Please, show us your code, actual output and expected results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of support vectors doesn't have a direct relationship to accuracy; it depends on the shape of the data (and your C/nu parameter).

Higher sigma means that the kernel is a "flatter" Gaussian and so the decision boundary is "smoother"; lower sigma makes it a "sharper" peak, and so the decision boundary is more flexible and able to reproduce strange shapes if they're the right answer. If sigma is very high, your data points will have a very wide influence; if very low, they will have a very small influence.

Thus, often, increasing the sigma values will result in more support vectors: for more-or-less the same decision boundary, more points will fall within the margin, because points become "fuzzier." Increased sigma also means, though, that the slack variables "moving" points past the margin are more expensive, and so the classifier might end up with a much smaller margin and fewer SVs. Of course, it also might just give you a dramatically different decision boundary with a completely different number of SVs.

In terms of maximizing accuracy, you should be doing a grid search on many different values of C and sigma and choosing the one that gives you the best performance on e.g. 3-fold cross-validation on your training set. One reasonable approach is to choose from e.g. `2.^(-9:3:18)` for C and `median_eval * 2.^(-4:2:10)`; those numbers are fairly arbitrary, but they're ones I've used with success in the past.